# Tinymce Editor Just Adding Text

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-5

I am using the Tinymce Editor. When I copy and paste any HTML page, it looks the same in the editor.

I just want to add it as text to the editor.

https://jsfiddle(.)net/hny4oawr/

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the paste plugin's [`paste_as_text`.](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/paste/#paste_as_text)

https://jsfiddle.net/z97sLx1p/